# Redirecting to a particular page/session with updated data in asp.net using session or some other way

Tags: c#, .net, session-state

I have a page where the data is by default loaded with the daterange of Sysdate to SYSDATE+18. The date can be selected over a dropdown. Which ever date user selects it shows the data's in date range of that **selected date** to **selected date+18 days**.

So based the Data in page is changing. But the page by default loads with SYSDATE.And each row has amend/Delete functionality. Now if a user click on Amend/Delete then user will be redirected to Amend that partcular record in a screen. In that screen there is a back button [image]

The back button click event has been written like that

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Rota.aspx");
        }
```

So it is redirecting the Main Page with data loaded as per Sysdate. How could I display that particular date's data Which I amended in Amend screen - Also it would be showing the updated data.? Probably use of session would help..any suggesion guys how could I proceed with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the options here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I managed to use the Previous.Page property to get something similar for me.

Comment: Could you add the information of the link to your answer? The link may be broken in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Can be Done via

```
Session["Date"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Read from session

```
var date = (DateTime)Session["Date"] ;
```

OR
You can set the postbackurl property of the button to the page you want to redirect.
Then on that page you can use

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
```

once this is done

```
if(PreviousPage != null)
{
   var name = PreviousPage.propertyname;
  //OR
   var control = PreviousPage.Controls[0].FindControl("controlname");
}
```